# Somehow my git develop branch got merged into my master branch

Tags: git, git-flow

I am using git-flow, but that's not important. My master branch is production and my develop branch is for development.

This morning, my master branch (this is my production release) hadn't been touched for weeks (since my last release). Now, when I look at my master branch, it has all of my commits from my develop branch.

I don't see a merge in the `git log` so I am confused how I can get my master branch back to its boring self.

How can I find this rouge merge to my master branch and reverse it without losing my development work?

**Edit:**

Does this provide enough information to know what happened?

Here is the output of `git reflog`:

```
0fe067c HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
300ba32 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from develop to master
06f1dd9 HEAD@{2}: pull: Fast-forward
0fe067c HEAD@{3}: commit: Add back prefix.
815ffe8 HEAD@{4}: pull: Fast-forward
f4c3e23 HEAD@{5}: pull: Fast-forward
93d1037 HEAD@{6}: pull: Fast-forward
e027c53 HEAD@{7}: commit: Don't commit changes to Prefix
96e37a9 HEAD@{8}: commit: Update URLs based on current server
```

Comment: Are you tagging you master before release to production?

Comment: If I had to revert to a particular commit, I could do that but I would rather figure out what happened here so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: you can search the `git reflog` to find out more about what can have happened

Comment: Maybe it was a rebase from develop to master (and that is why you don't see the merge commit).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the merge has been fast-forwarded, it won't create a merge commit which is probably what happened.

So, from there, where do we go ?

Well, if you have a remote still pointing to the good commit, you can reset your local branch pretty easily:

`git reset --hard origin/master` (where `remote/branch`)

Else, it's a little bit more complicated, but still: you can filter your reflog to only log master information:

`git reflog show master`

And if the logged info make sense, then you can reset:

`git reset --hard master@{1}`

Note that `--hard` will discard all local change made to the working tree, if that's a trouble, use `--keep`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tag your production branch when you released?

Do you have any idea of the sha1 of the last release?

I like Simon Boudrias's answer but it could be as simple as locating the commit you want using `git log` and resetting the branch to that commit `git reset --hard <sha1>`.

Note: You might want to reset without the --hard part first to make sure it takes you to the point you want without losing information.

```
git co production
git log # find the sha1
git reset <sha1> # to check if this is the point you want
git co production
git reset --hard <sha1>
```

Since you are not deleting any commit from "development" you are not losing commits (as long as no one had been developing in production directly).